# Add data to a generic collection in java

Tags: java, generics

Is there any way i can add data to a generic collection in Java.
For eg:-

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class testGenerics {
    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        Vector<? extends Number> superNumberList = null;

        // I can do this
        Vector<Integer> subList = new Vector<Integer>();
        subList.add(2);
        superNumberList = subList;

        // But i cannot do this
        // Gives the below compilation error.
        //The method add(capture#2-of ? extends Number) in the type 
        //Vector<capture#2-of ? extends Number> is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)        
        superNumberList = new Vector<Integer>();
        superNumberList.add(new Integer(4));

        superNumberList = new Vector<Float>();
        superNumberList.add(new Float(4));
    }

}
```

As mentioned in my comments i have compilation errors when i try to add an Integer or Float data to superNumberList.

I am able to do it , the first way , but would like to do it the second way and not sure why Java does not allow me to do it the second way.

I have a suitation where i have a super class which has this superNumberList and all the subclasses are trying to use this same variable but has different data types in this collection like Integer , Float etc.

Answer (score 3):

A `Vector<? extends Number>` is a Vector of an unknown Number type. As such, you cannot add *anything* into it.

It could be a `Vector<Float>`. So you cannot add an `Integer`.

But it could also be a `Vector<Integer>`. So you cannot add a `Float`.

The only thing you know about it is that whatever you pull *out* of the Vector will be a `Number`.

---

If you have a superclass that has subclasses for `Integer`, `Float` and so on, you should make the superclass generic:

```
class SuperClassWithVector<T extends Number>{
    protected Vector<T> myVector;
}

class FloatSubClass extends SuperClassWithVector<Float>{
   // here myVector takes Float
}
```

---

If you want a `Vector` that can take both `Integer` and `Float` (not sure if that is what you want), then you can use a `Vector<Number>`.

Comment: This does explain why, but it doesn't answer the "is there a way..." part.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `? extends Number`:

```
Vector<Number> superNumberList = null;
...
superNumberList = new Vector<Number>();
superNumberList.add(new Integer(4));
superNumberList.add(new Float(4));
```

Comment: Are you sure the wildcard is superfluous ? If the client code has already defined a `Vector<Integer>`, it cannot pass that in as a `Vector<Number>` without an unchecked explicit cast.

Comment: If the client code was already defined as a Vector<Integer>, you would never be able to add a Float to it.  Also, explicitly casting a Vector<Integer> to a Vector<Number> is an error.

Comment: Similarly, casting a Vector<Integer> to a Vector<? extends Number> is an error.

Comment: Actually, you can add a `Float` to a `Vector<Integer>` after an ugly cast (the problems will only occur when you try to get it back as an `Integer`); and you can also do that ugly cast as just `(Vector)` to make the compiler swallow it.

Comment: You may be able to get the compiler to swallow it, but it will still result in a runtime exception once executed.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: I agree with everything that you're saying. It's just that I think the question is quite specific about using `Vector<Integer>`. So you should perhaps point out that it's impossible and provide this solution as the closest match (rather than assume the wildcard is not needed).

Comment: The thing is i am adding the getter and setter methods to my super class itself for this list.  I am trying to avoid adding getter and setter methods to the individual subclasses.  And without giving the WildCard , i cannot retrieve them in my client code. I am not able to format my code in the comments .But here is the code piece.                                               public Vector<? extends Number> getList() 
 {
  return superNumberList;
 }
 
 public void setList(Vector<? extends Number> list) {
  superNumberList = list;
 }                          clientcode.setList(Vector<Integer>)